# (HA)Proxy with mutual TLS/SSL auth

Tags: ssl, haproxy

Problem: I have an application connecting to several databases (Redis, Riak, etc) via TCP through HAProxy. Like this:
app -> HAProxy --TLS--> HAProxy -> Redis

Access to HAProxy on Redis side is managed by Chef via iptables. We already use CFSSL for mutual TLS authentication on Nginx<->Nginx connections because it's way faster than waiting until Chef updates configuration.

Wanna make HAProxy on application side use client-side TLS certificate when connecting to HAProxy on DB side.

Actually any other proxy will do on client side but we'd like to keep things simple.

Comment: You appear to be asking how to configure HAProxy to [use a client cert when connecting to the back-end](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#5.2-crt) and [require a client cert when accepting a connection on the front-end](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#5.1-verify), but these are both documented, so it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking, thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the two keywords linked in the previous comment.

Comment: Yeah, I got it, thanks a lot.